# How to get ChatGPT to create photo realistic images?

Tags: chatgpt, image-generation, text-to-image, dall-e

I am trying to create photorealistic images in chatGPT however it always seems to give me more hype real cartoons than Photos. I have tried the below prompts:

Photorealistic, realism, photoshoot, portrait photography. Is there a template I can use to guarantee a Realistic Photo every time?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the API - there are settings you can set to make it more realistic-
try changing the quality parameter from standard to HD